# When is $V_\kappa \prec_{\Sigma_1} V$

Tags: set-theory

We know that for uncountable $\kappa$, $H_\kappa \prec_{\Sigma_1} V$ where $H_\kappa$ is the $\kappa$ level of the hereditary hierarchy, and $\prec_{\Sigma_1}$ indicates absoluteness of $\Sigma_1$ formulas. This can be proved via a combination of lowenheim skolem and mostowski collapse ([as can be seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690624/is-it-true-that-v-and-h-omega-1-agree-on-the-truth-value-of-sigma-1-se?rq=1)).

We also know that $\kappa = \beth_\kappa \iff V_\kappa = H_\kappa$, so from this we get that $V_\kappa \prec_{\Sigma_1} V$ when $\kappa = \beth_\kappa$, i.e, when $V_\kappa = H_\kappa$.

What about the converse? Does $V_\kappa \prec_{\Sigma_1} V $ imply $H_\kappa = V_\kappa$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_1}V$ holds. Observe that the sentence

> Every set is equipotent with an ordinal.

is $\Pi_2$, and it holds over $V$. Hence it also holds over $V_\kappa$. [By my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3809015/53976), it implies $\kappa$ is a beth fixed point, so we have $H_\kappa=V_\kappa$.